# How to Hide certain userform fields during initialization?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

So I have a userform that consist of `Multipages`and one of the pages contain `togglebuttons` which hide and unhide fields on the Userform as well as on the excel worksheet. The picture below shows the togglebutton page.

[image]

The code for HAZOP/ SIL & LOPA is the same except which fields it hides is different. Below is the code for HAZOP togglebutton.

```
Private Sub togbHAZOP_Click()

    If togbHAZOP = True Then

        Sheets("Updated Hours EST").Rows("6:27").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Sheets("SCOPE").Rows("31:37").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Sheets("SUMMARY").Rows("5:8").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Frame5.Enabled = True
        Frame5.Visible = True
        Frame6.Enabled = True
        Frame6.Visible = True
        Frame7.Enabled = True
        Frame7.Visible = True
        HazOp.Enabled = True
        HazOp.Visible = True

    Else
        Sheets("Updated Hours EST").Rows("6:27").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Sheets("SCOPE").Rows("31:37").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Sheets("SUMMARY").Rows("5:8").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Frame5.Enabled = False
        Frame5.Visible = False
        Frame6.Enabled = False
        Frame6.Visible = False
        Frame7.Enabled = False
        Frame7.Visible = False
        HazOp.Enabled = False
        HazOp.Visible = False

    End If

End Sub
```

Code for Initialization at the moment but it doesn't work, gives an error saying `"Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method"`

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    WizardProp.MultiPage1.Value = 0
    Me.MultiPage1.Style = fmTabStyleNone
    togbHAZOP.Frame5.Enabled = False
    togbHAZOP.Frame5.Visible = False
    togbHAZOP.Frame6.Enabled = False
    togbHAZOP.Frame6.Visible = False
    togbHAZOP.Frame7.Enabled = False
    togbHAZOP.Frame7.Visible = False
    togbHAZOP.HazOp.Enabled = False
    togbHAZOP.HazOp.Visible = False

End Sub
```

The issue I am having is **how do I hide certain fields within the userform at the beginning of the code** and based upon the user's selection using the `togglebuttons`will hide/unhide because at the moment I have to click on the togglebuttons then unclick to get it where the linked fields are hidden and doing that everytime during initialization can be a nuisance.

Comment: When you debug it do you know which line you get that error on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you can reduce the code like below. Replace `True` with `togbHAZOP.Value` and `False` with `Not togbHAZOP.Value` in the `If togbHAZOP = True` part. So you don't need to repeat the whole code.

```
Private Sub togbHAZOP_Click()
    Sheets("Updated Hours EST").Rows("6:27").EntireRow.Hidden = Not togbHAZOP.Value
    Sheets("SCOPE").Rows("31:37").EntireRow.Hidden = Not togbHAZOP.Value
    Sheets("SUMMARY").Rows("5:8").EntireRow.Hidden = Not togbHAZOP.Value
    Frame5.Enabled = togbHAZOP.Value
    Frame5.Visible = togbHAZOP.Value
    Frame6.Enabled = togbHAZOP.Value
    Frame6.Visible = togbHAZOP.Value
    Frame7.Enabled = togbHAZOP.Value
    Frame7.Visible = togbHAZOP.Value
    HazOp.Enabled = togbHAZOP.Value
    HazOp.Visible = togbHAZOP.Value    
End Sub
```

Since `togbHAZOP` is a toggle it does not have a frame `togbHAZOP.Frame5` that's probably the issue here. It should probably be something like:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    WizardProp.MultiPage1.Value = 0
    Me.MultiPage1.Style = fmTabStyleNone
    Me.Frame5.Enabled = False
    Me.Frame5.Visible = False
    Me.Frame6.Enabled = False
    Me.Frame6.Visible = False
    Me.Frame7.Enabled = False
    Me.Frame7.Visible = False
    Me.HazOp.Enabled = False
    Me.HazOp.Visible = False
End Sub
```